Next.js with Tailwind CSS and shadcn/ui: Prevent Overscroll Leading to White Space
I'm working on a Next.js project using Tailwind CSS to create a layout with a sidebar on the left, a header on top, and the main content area. However, I'm encountering an issue where users can overscroll, causing a white space to appear at the bottom of the page, particularly when I use the shadcn/ui switch component.
"use client"

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { z } from "zod"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormDescription,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import { Switch } from "@/components/ui/switch"

const FormSchema = z.object({
    marketing_emails: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
    security_emails: z.boolean(),
})

export default function Home() {
    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            security_emails: true,
        },
    })

    function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
        console.log(data)
    }
  return (
      <div className="flex h-screen">
        {/* Sidebar */}
        <div className="w-64 bg-gray-800 text-white p-4">
          <div className="bg-red-500 h-full">
            {/* Sidebar Content */}
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Main Content */}
        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col overflow-hidden">
          {/* Header */}
          <div className="bg-white shadow p-4">
            <div className="bg-green-500 h-12">
              {/* Header Content */}
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* Main */}
          <div className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto p-4">
              <div className="bg-blue-500 h-full mb-4">
                  <div className={"h-72 bg-yellow-200"}>
                      <p>Coming soon</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className={"h-72 bg-orange-200"}>
                      <p>Coming soon</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className={"h-72 bg-purple-50"}>
                      <p>Coming soon</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className={"h-72 bg-blue-200"}>
                      <p>Coming soon</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className={"h-72 bg-pink-200"}>
                      <p>Coming soon</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className={"bg-green-200 h-72"}>
                      <Form {...form}>
                          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-full space-y-6">
                              <div>
                                  <h3 className="mb-4 text-lg font-medium">Email Notifications</h3>
                                  <div className="space-y-4">
                                      <FormField
                                          control={form.control}
                                          name="marketing_emails"
                                          render={({field}) => (
                                              <FormItem
                                                  className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between rounded-lg border p-4">
                                                  <div className="space-y-0.5">
                                                      <FormLabel className="text-base">
                                                          Marketing emails
                                                      </FormLabel>
                                                      <FormDescription>
                                                          Receive emails about new products, features, and more.
                                                      </FormDescription>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <FormControl>
                                                      <Switch
                                                          checked={field.value}
                                                          onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                                                      />
                                                  </FormControl>
                                              </FormItem>
                                          )}
                                      />
                                      <FormField
                                          control={form.control}
                                          name="security_emails"
                                          render={({field}) => (
                                              <FormItem
                                                  className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between rounded-lg border p-4">
                                                  <div className="space-y-0.5">
                                                      <FormLabel className="text-base">Security emails</FormLabel>
                                                      <FormDescription>
                                                          Receive emails about your account security.
                                                      </FormDescription>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <FormControl>
                                                      <Switch
                                                          checked={field.value}
                                                          onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                                                          disabled
                                                          aria-readonly
                                                      />
                                                  </FormControl>
                                              </FormItem>
                                          )}
                                      />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                          </form>
                      </Form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

Code for demo purposes only

See white space below the green box

I would put the h-screen on the body tag in the layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body className='h-screen'>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}

And remove it in the Home (page.tsx)
'use client'

import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { z } from 'zod'

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
} from '@/components/ui/form'
import { Switch } from '@/components/ui/switch'

const FormSchema = z.object({
  marketing_emails: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
  security_emails: z.boolean(),
})

export default function Home() {
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      security_emails: true,
    },
  })

  function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    console.log(data)
  }
  return (
    <div className='flex'>
      {/* Sidebar */}
      <div className='w-64 bg-gray-800 text-white p-4'>
        <div className='bg-red-500 h-full'>{/* Sidebar Content */}</div>
      </div>

      {/* Main Content */}
      <div className='flex-1 flex flex-col overflow-hidden'>
        {/* Header */}
        <div className='bg-white shadow p-4'>
          <div className='bg-green-500 h-12'>{/* Header Content */}</div>
        </div>

        {/* Main */}
        <div className='flex-1 overflow-y-auto p-4'>
          <div className='bg-blue-500 h-full mb-4'>
            <div className={'h-72 bg-yellow-200'}>
              <p>Coming soon</p>
            </div>
            <div className={'h-72 bg-orange-200'}>
              <p>Coming soon</p>
            </div>
            <div className={'h-72 bg-purple-50'}>
              <p>Coming soon</p>
            </div>
            <div className={'h-72 bg-blue-200'}>
              <p>Coming soon</p>
            </div>
            <div className={'h-72 bg-pink-200'}>
              <p>Coming soon</p>
            </div>
            <div className={'bg-green-200 h-72'}>
              <Form {...form}>
                <form
                  onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                  className='w-full space-y-6'
                >
                  <div>
                    <h3 className='mb-4 text-lg font-medium'>
                      Email Notifications
                    </h3>
                    <div className='space-y-4'>
                      <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name='marketing_emails'
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <FormItem className='flex flex-row items-center justify-between rounded-lg border p-4'>
                            <div className='space-y-0.5'>
                              <FormLabel className='text-base'>
                                Marketing emails
                              </FormLabel>
                              <FormDescription>
                                Receive emails about new products, features, and
                                more.
                              </FormDescription>
                            </div>
                            <FormControl>
                              <Switch
                                checked={field.value}
                                onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                              />
                            </FormControl>
                          </FormItem>
                        )}
                      />
                      <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name='security_emails'
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <FormItem className='flex flex-row items-center justify-between rounded-lg border p-4'>
                            <div className='space-y-0.5'>
                              <FormLabel className='text-base'>
                                Security emails
                              </FormLabel>
                              <FormDescription>
                                Receive emails about your account security.
                              </FormDescription>
                            </div>
                            <FormControl>
                              <Switch
                                checked={field.value}
                                onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                                disabled
                                aria-readonly
                              />
                            </FormControl>
                          </FormItem>
                        )}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                </form>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Hope that helps.

This answer resolved the issue for me, put "relative" on all your FormItem. I had a long form with a lot of selects and checkboxes and could not figure out why I was having a huge whitespace at the bottom of my page.
